# Multiple Flink Statefun jobs on the same Flink cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-statefun

Is it possible to register multiple statefun jobs on the same Flink cluster?

I saw this configuration: "statefun.flink-job-name" ([here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-3.2/docs/deployment/configurations/)). but it seems to be relevant to the Flink cluster configuration. So it looks like I can define a single job name.

Im wondering if I can create more than one module.yaml and register it to the Flink cluster without interfere other modules.